# Converting rails 2 generators to rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, code-generation, generator, rails-3-upgrade

How difficult is it to convert rails 2 generators to rails 3?  I keep finding useful plugins but then finding that the generators are only for rails 2.  I realize some of it is just a convenience, but if migrating the generator to rails 3 is as simple as tweaking a few lines in the generator code, I would be down to just do that (and commit the work to github for future users as well).

Here's one such generator I've been thinking about using, for example (from [feedback](https://github.com/jsboulanger/feedback))

```
require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/lib/insert_routes.rb")

class FeedbackFormGenerator < Rails::Generator::Base

  attr_accessor :name, 
    :model_class_name,
    :controller_class_name,
    :helper_class_name,
    :mailer_class_name


  def initialize(runtime_args, runtime_options = {})
    super
    @name = (runtime_args[0] || "feedback").downcase
    @model_class_name = name.classify
    @mailer_class_name = "#{@model_class_name}Mailer"
    @controller_class_name = "#{@model_class_name.pluralize}Controller"
    @helper_class_name = "#{@model_class_name.pluralize}Helper"
    #@js_framework = (runtime_options[''])

  end

  def manifest
    record do |m|

      puts "hello"
      add_model(m)
      add_mailer(m)
      add_controller(m)
      add_helper(m)
      add_views(m)
      add_routes(m)
      add_unit_test(m)
      add_functional_test(m)
      add_stylesheet(m)
      add_javascript(m)
      add_images(m)
    end
  end


  def add_stylesheet(m)
    m.directory 'public/stylesheets'
    m.file 'feedback.css', 'public/stylesheets/feedback.css'

  end

  def add_javascript(m)
    m.directory 'public/javascripts'
    file_name = options[:jquery] ? 'jquery.feedback.js' : 'prototype.feedback.js'
    m.file file_name, "public/javascripts/#{file_name}"
  end

  def add_images(m)
    m.directory 'public/images/feedback'
    m.file "images/feedback_tab.png", "public/images/feedback/feedback_tab.png"
    m.file "images/feedback_tab_h.png", "public/images/feedback/feedback_tab_h.png"
    m.file "images/closelabel.gif", "public/images/feedback/closelabel.gif"
    m.file "images/loading.gif", "public/images/feedback/loading.gif"
  end

  def add_model(m)
    m.template 'feedback_model.rb.erb', "app/models/#{name}.rb"
  end

  def add_mailer(m)
    m.template 'feedback_mailer.rb.erb', "app/models/#{name}_mailer.rb"
    m.directory "app/views/#{name}_mailer"
    m.file 'views/feedback_mailer/feedback.html.erb', "app/views/#{name}_mailer/feedback.html.erb"

  end

  def add_controller(m)
    m.template 'feedbacks_controller.rb.erb', "app/controllers/#{name.pluralize}_controller.rb"
  end

  def add_helper(m)
    template_name = options[:jquery] ? 'feedbacks_helper.rb.jquery.erb' : 'feedbacks_helper.rb.prototype.erb'
    m.template template_name, "app/helpers/#{name.pluralize}_helper.rb"
  end

  def add_views(m)
    m.directory "app/views/#{name.pluralize}"
    m.file 'views/feedbacks/new.html.erb', "app/views/#{name.pluralize}/new.html.erb"
  end

  def add_routes(m)
    m.route_name "new_feedback", "feedbacks/new", {:controller => name.pluralize, :action => "new"}
    m.route_name "feedback", "feedbacks", {:controller => name.pluralize, :action => "create"}
  end

  def add_unit_test(m)
    m.template 'feedback_test.rb.erb', "test/unit/#{name}_test.rb"
    m.template 'feedback_mailer_test.rb.erb', "test/unit/#{name}_mailer_test.rb"
  end

  def add_functional_test(m)
    m.template 'feedbacks_controller_test.rb.erb', "test/functional/#{name.pluralize}_controller_test.rb"    
  end

  protected 

  def add_options!(opt)
    opt.separator ''
    opt.separator 'Options:'
    opt.on("--jquery",
      "Use jquery Javascript framework, default is Prototyp")           { |v| options[:jquery] = true }
  end
end
```

Comment: I have the same question.  I want to use wizardly, but the original source is only Rails 2 compliant.  I then found someone who made a Rails 3 branch (https://github.com/jfelchner/wizardly), but the generator is still in Rails 2 code.

Comment: They're quite different... There exists Rails-3 fork for feedback, by the way: https://github.com/alkesh/feedback

Answer (score 4):

It really depends on the sort of generator it is.  A lot of the internals of Rails have changed a lot between 2 and 3.  Let me show you my recent experience in converting a very simple migration generator which I have in one of my apps from 2 to 3.

Here's the 2 code:

```
class LegacyMigrationGenerator < MigrationGenerator
  def manifest
    record do |m|
      m.migration_template 'legacy_migration.rb', 'db/migrate'
    end
  end
end
```

And here's the 3 code:

```
require 'rails/generators/active_record'

class LegacyMigrationGenerator < ActiveRecord::Generators::Base
  source_root File.expand_path('../templates', __FILE__)
  def create_migration_file
    migration_template "legacy_migration.rb", "db/migrate/#{file_name}.rb"
  end
end
```

So, as you can see - totally different method to override, had to inherit from a generator now, had to call this `source_root` now (used to be automatic), and no longer calling the `migration_template` in a block.

This small conversion took me about three hours to hunt down all the pieces through the source.  The best part was that I didn't have to change my template at all (and I believe that will be true for most generators).

All that being said, I think migration generation is probably the least well documented, [looking at the generator guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html) it really doesn't seem too challenging to recreate generators in Rails3.  Definitely worth taking a crack at in my opinion.

Also, I know that one of the authors of that guide has a book coming out soon with a chapter all about generators - so it's definitely something which will be getting more attention.

Comment: Thanks.  I did a bit more researching on the topic, looking at other Rails 3 generators, and found almost all of what I needed.  The only thing I couldn't figure out was how to pass a variable to a template in Rails 3 generators, which was done easily with a `:assigns` hash value in Rails 2 generators.